# Why does this Telerik Radgrid work some of the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a unusual situation that I just cannot seem to resolve.  I have a Telerik RadGrid setup to use an .ascx web user control to edit records and adding new records.  The form has 1 ASP.net DropdownList that works fine when I edit a record. However when I try to add a record the application crashes with this error message:

> 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
>    Parameter name: value Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>    Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
>    Parameter name: value

Here is the code used to construct the dropdown on the .ascx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
                    DataTextField="StatusDescription" DataValueField="StatusDescription" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Status") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select" Value="">
                        </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

The datasource for the dropdown is using an EntityDataSource and that code is shown below:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=TipsFileEntities1" DefaultContainerName="TipsFileEntities1" EntitySetName="Status"
                    Select="it.[StatusDescription], it.[StatusCode]" AutoPage="true" OrderBy="it.[StatusDescription]">
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Can anyone explain why would the form render without error for an edit and not for a record add? And any suggestions on how I can fix it.   I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution but that does not help.

Thanks
Perry

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the solution to this problem.  I was missing a setting in the DropDownList. the corrected code is shown below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
                    DataTextField="StatusDescription" DataValueField="StatusDescription" AppendDataBoundItems ="true" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Status") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I had left out the AppendDataBoundItems="true".

Code now works for adding and editing records